# What's a virtual package?

Tags: package-management

I always see the term "virtual package" when it comes to packages but what are they? Could someone please elaborate for a total noob, please. Thanks!

Answer (score 25):

> A virtual package is a generic name that applies to any one of a group
> of packages, all of which provide similar basic functionality. For
> example, both the tin and trn programs are news readers, and should
> therefore satisfy any dependency of a program that required a news
> reader on a system, in order to work or to be useful. They are
> therefore both said to provide the "virtual package" called
> news-reader.
>
> Similarly, smail and sendmail both provide the functionality of a mail
> transport agent. They are therefore said to provide the virtual
> package, "mail transport agent". If either one is installed, then any
> program depending on the installation of a mail-transport-agent will
> be satisfied by the existence of this virtual package.
>
> Debian provides a mechanism so that, if more than one package which
> provide the same virtual package is installed on a system, then system
> administrators can set one as the preferred package.<sup>[Debian Manuals](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/pkg-basics.en.html#virtual)</sup>