# Given a package name (e.g. libhdf5-serial-dev_1.8.16+docs-4ubuntu1.1_all.deb), how can I know in which Ubuntu distribution(s) it is available via apt?

Tags: apt, package-management, packaging

Given a package name (e.g.,  [`libhdf5-serial-dev_1.8.16+docs-4ubuntu1.1_all.deb`](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/16.04/ubuntu-updates-universe-amd64/libhdf5-serial-dev_1.8.16+docs-4ubuntu1.1_all.deb.html)), how can I know in which Ubuntu distribution(s) it is available via `apt-get` (`apt-get install  libhdf5-serial-dev=1.8.16+docs-4ubuntu1.1`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest and convenient way to search a package for a supported release is to do a [package search](https://packages.ubuntu.com). For this particular example, if you search for libhdf5-serial-dev for any distribution a.k.a Ubuntu release and any section, you'll see that it is available in Security repositories of 16.04. And since 19.04, it has become a virtual-package which is being provided by [libhdf5-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libhdf5-dev&searchon=names).

#### Related Q&A:

- [What's a virtual package?](https://askubuntu.com/q/652326/816190)

Comment: Thanks very much!